# how to calculate vowel occurance ratio in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, mapreduce

I'm new to scala and I'm trying to the following exercise:

An English teacher hates sentences with excessive vowels and wants you to write a program that can grade millions of SAT essays by calculating the average number of vowels per sentence in the essay. For example, if the essay contains the following text:
able was I ere I saw elba
a man a plan a canal panama
the future is uncertain and the end is always near

then the essay gets a vowel score of 0.3701234567901235 since the vowel to character ratio in each sentence is: 0.4, 0.37037037037037035, 0.34. In this English teacher's world, characters include anything that is not a vowel (spaces, punctuation, etc.).

Write a function essay_grade that, for a given essay provided as an argument, calculates the vowel ratio and returns (1-the ratio) times 100 as the grade on the exam. The final grade should be returned as a truncated Int (62 for the example case). For the purposes of this problem, you must use both the map function as well as the reduce function and you can assume the text is in lower case (i.e., it should work for the example above)

For now, I can calculate the occurrence of each individual character, and I can also find the total length of the text, but I'm stuck with how to calculate the percentage of each character and then group them by vowels. Can anyone help me figure out how to the next steps? Thank you!

The following is what I've done:

```
val sample_essay = """able was i ere i saw elba
a man a plan a canal panama
the future is uncertain and the end is always near"""

// the following gives me the occurance of each char
sample_essay.toLowerCase.toArray
    .map(w=>(w,1))
    .groupBy(_._1) //map and group by category
    .map(w => (w._1,(w._2.map(_=>1).reduce(_+_)))) // sum up


//the following part give me the text length to be 140
sample_essay.toLowerCase.toArray
    .map(w=>(w,1))
    .groupBy(_._1) //map and group by category
    .map(w => (w._1,(w._2.map(_=>1).reduce(_+_)))) // sum up
    .map(_._2).reduce(_+_).toDouble


// I think for my next step, I should calculate the occurrence ratio of each character compared with the full text
// Then, I need to group by vowels and calculate the sum of the ratio of vowels
// but I'm stuck with how to do these steps...
```

Comment: 1) I assume you meant text length is 104, not 140. 2) You can simply do `sample_essay.length` to get the total character count (including white space). 3) You can use `groupMap` instead of `groupBy + map` 4) While there are binary ways to check for a vowel, I would create a static list of vowel since they are easily countable. Next write a function that return `true` if character is a vowel, `false` otherwise and `groupBy` this function to create two groups then reduce

Comment: You have the count per character. You know what characters are vowels (there are five of them). What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> def essay_grade(text: String): Int = {
     |   val lines = text.linesIterator.map(_.trim).toArray
     |   val ratio = lines.map(line => line.count("aeiou".contains).toDouble / line.size)
     |   ((1 - ratio.reduce(_ + _) / ratio.size) * 100).toInt
     | }
def essay_grade(text: String): Int

scala> essay_grade(sample_essay)
val res0: Int = 62
```